# Unknown getter in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I had setup google analytics in my app for building dashboard. When I `dd();` i'm getting data in [image]

When i run this code:

```
    @foreach($datas as $data)
        @foreach($data as $dat)
            {{$dat}}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

It is giving all data of collection in single row. And when I run:

```
    @foreach($datas as $data)
        @foreach($data as $dat)
            {{$dat->pageViews}}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

It throws error `Unknown getter 'pageViews'`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using your loop

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
    @foreach($data as $dat)
        {{$dat->pageViews}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

You have to use it

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
    @foreach($data as $dat)
        {{$dat['pageViews']}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Just to add to this, you need to do this because you are working with arrays, not objects. Hence the need to access it with `['pageViews']` rather than `->pageViews`

Comment: @Kukece i'm getting error `Cannot use object of type Carbon\Carbon as array` as `date` is in carbon format.

Comment: date is an array element that holds an carbon object instance , you can't access `date` like you access an array instead use `['date']->` to access carbon class methods

Comment: I tried your method `{{$data['date']->date}}` it returns error `Unknown getter 'date` How can I pharse carbon object instance in view

Comment: Do `dd($dat['date])` and see which property of carbon you need to display. If its for example time then use something like `$dat['date]->time`